# How to set a non existing dimensions measurement unit in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, dimensions

In WooCommerce I would like to change cm to ft my products display in height, width and length,

You can see the products with their title below:

[image]

Comment: You mean only label ?

Comment: i want to change label only.

Comment: You should have a look at `woocommerce_product_data_tabs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code that will change the displayed dimensions unit in front end:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_dimensions', 'custom_dimention_unit', 20, 2 );
function custom_dimention_unit( $dimension_string, $dimensions ){
    $dimension_string = implode( ' x ', array_filter( array_map( 'wc_format_localized_decimal', $dimensions ) ) );

    if ( ! empty( $dimension_string ) ) {
        $dimension_string .= ' ' . __('ft');
    } else {
        $dimension_string = __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    return $dimension_string;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

---

**Update:** Make dimension unit "ft" *(feet)* globally (everywhere)

Woocommerce dimension available units are "m", "cm", "mm", "in" and "yd".

> But **"ft" is not available** in the  Woocommerce > Settings > Products > Mesurements section.

What you can do is the following:

1. Paste the following line in your function.php file and save:

   ```
    update_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit', 'ft' );
   ```
2. Browse any page of your web site.
3. Remove or comment the line of code from your function.php file and save.
4. You can also remove the first code snippet as it's not needed anymore.
5. **You are done.**

You will get something like:

[image]

And in backend:

[image]

---

> For info, to change the dimensions unit in **Woocommerce** > **Settings** > **Products**:
>
> [image]

Comment: Showing error...........Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'custom_dimention_unit' not found or invalid function name in C:\xampp\htdocs\final\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 286

Comment: Your code is good can you send it again rename hook same like my website

Comment: i want to change everywhere

Comment: but my issue same showing: Dimensions 292 x 244 x 600 cm

Comment: i am using wordpress 4.9.7

Comment: @AsiaticGroup So you will have to add **in your question (editing it)** all related code or/and details related to this option that you have in backend…

Answer (score 1):

Modify WooCommerce settings field to add a new dimension unit to the list.

Add the following codes to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_settings', 'add_custom_dimension_unit', 20, 1 );
function add_custom_dimension_unit( $settings ){

            foreach( $settings as $key => $field ) {
                if( $field['id'] == 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' ) {
                    $field['options']['ft'] = __( 'ft', 'woocommerce' );
                    $settings[ $key ] = $field;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return $settings;
        }
```

Comment: I think this should be the correct and accepted answer.